# Verify input box text using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have gone through other similar questions and the general advice was to use the `get_attribute()` method with input `'value'`.

However, this doesn't seem to work in my case.

The tag I am trying to test is -:

```
<input class="form-control required" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-mail / Username" required="" type="text" value="">
```

and the code I am using is as follows -:

```
def enter_keys_by_id(self, id, text):
    """
    Finds a form element by ID and then proceeds
    to enter text into the form.
    """
    find_element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(id)
    assert find_element.get_attribute('value') == ""
    find_element.send_keys(text)
    assert find_element.get_attribute('value') == text
    return find_element
```

with the function call -:

```
enter_keys_by_id("email", "someemail@email.com")
```

The `'value'` attribute is set to blank in the tag. How would I go about it in this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

So, you type email to the "empty" input, but I think that you need to submit the form, ie `save` the `value` to the input before retrieveing it. I guess you are trying to verify that the email was saved correctly, so you can:

1. Type email
2. Submit the form (you didn't provide html, but I guess there is some submit button near to the email field)
3. And after that try to `assert find_element.get_attribute('value') == text` (or to wait for the input with value='your text')

Comment: I use `find_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` for quick submission but I think you're right. Maybe I should try `submit()`?

Comment: you can try submitting by this: `self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']").click()` submit buttons usually are a type of `submit` if not, then would be good to see a piece of html around the email input

Comment: In the "email" case, I use `send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` and in other cases, I have used `click()` to submit. It's still the same - returns a blank line when I try to print it.

Comment: so, after you submit, you see "by eyes" that this exact input contains your email and value of this input is blank? then you might try to get text from it, like: `assert find_element.get_text() == text`